# Rotating div rotating back to previous position when not meant to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is just a prototype for a nav bar that I'm building, and I thought about having a rotating one in a 3d aspect. It all works well and fine except for the part where if the mouse is hovered over certain areas after it rotates, it starts rotating back when it shouldn't be (one area is a couple of pixels to the left of the 2nd white bar, and when hovering just above the dropdowns)

I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this problem and would welcome any solution to this?

PS: I would also like to learn how to do this particular rotation using javascript/jquery, but haven't been able to find a successful 3d rotation for it.

Here is the raw code:

HTML:

```
<head>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,700italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<div id="bannerMaster">
<div id="banner" class="animate">
  <div id="welcomeMessage">
    <b>
      WELCOME TO DERP
    </b>
  </div>
  <div id="menuNav">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li id="home" class="navigation">
        <a href="">
          <b>
            <div id="home2">
              Home
            </div>
          </b>
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              List 1 Derpface 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              List 1 Derpface 2
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <div class="stuffCSS">
      </div>
      <li id="aboutUs" class="navigation">
        <a href="">
          <b>
            About
          </b>
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              List 2 Derpface 3
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              List 2 Derpface 4
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <div class="stuffCSS">
      </div>
      <li id="contactUs" class="navigation">
        <a href="">
          <b>
            Contact
          </b>
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              List 3 Derpface 5
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              List 3 Derpface 6
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <div class="stuffCSS">
      </div>
      <li id="faq" class="navigation">
        <a href="">
          <b>
            F.A.Q
          </b>
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              List 4 Derpface 7
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <div class="listText">
                List 4 Derpface 8
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.animate
{
  /*-webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);*/
  /*-webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg);*/
}
.animate:hover
{
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}
#bannerMaster
{
  position: fixed;
  margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
  z-index: 9999999999;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 100000000000000px;
  -moz-perspective: 100000000000000px;
  perspective: 100000000000000px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: center center;
  -moz-perspective-origin: center center;
  perspective-origin: center center;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #999;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
}
#banner
{
  position: relative;
  height: 75px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s linear;
  transition: transform 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#banner>div 
{
  line-height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  background-position:center center;
}
#welcomeMessage
{
  line-height: 75px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(37px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(37px);
  transform: translateZ(37px);
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #999 inset;
  font-size: 28px;
}
#menuNav
{
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(37px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(37px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(37px);
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #999 inset;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0;
}

/* dropdowns */
#nav
{
  margin: 0 0 0 1%;
}
.navigation
{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 24.4%;
  height: 248px;
}
.stuffCSS
{
  margin: 16px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 2px #fff inset;
  height: 40px;
  width: 1px;
}
ul
{
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li
{
  display: block;
}
ul li ul li
{
  line-height: 43px;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0px;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #111;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #999 inset,
    0 0 5px #999;
}
li ul
{
  display: none;
}
ul li a 
{
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #999;
  color: #DDDDDD;
}
li:hover ul 
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
li:hover li
{
  font-size: 13px;
}
ul li a:hover
{
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #DDD;
}

/* derp */
#infoDerp
{
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000,
    0px 0px 25px #A10000;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 175px 0 0 80%;
}
```

Javascript:

Edit: Editted JS using Jason P's commented suggestion.

```
$('#nav .navigation').hover(function() { 
    $(this).stop().animate({top:-12}); 
}, function() { 
    $(this).stop().animate({top:0}); 
});
```

code in codepen.io: http://codepen.io/zephyr/pen/qJcpd

Comment: Try to reuse code when you can: http://jsfiddle.net/L99fe/

Comment: Cheers for that, that was one area I didn't really know how to do properly, it kept screwing up as js isn't my strongest language, still improving on it, ended up doing what I did to make it work. Any idea on what could be causing the problem however?